# Raspberry pi install sailsJS

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, sails.js, raspbian, waterline

I'm trying to install Sails JS on raspberry pi (B+, raspian) but I have a lot of error :/
I install NodeJS with this tutorial : 
http://joshondesign.com/2013/10/23/noderpi

And we I try

```
sudo su
npm -g install sails
```

I have :

```
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/promised-io/-/promised-io-0.3.3.tgz
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chown '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/LICENSE-MIT'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/LICENSE-MIT
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/LICENSE-MIT
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chown
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:222:7
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/i18n'
npm ERR! error rolling back  sails@0.10.5 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/i18n']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/i18n' }
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: maxmin@'^0.1.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","1.0.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:685:10)
npm ERR!     at /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:607:10
npm ERR!     at RegClient.get_ (/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:101:14)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:37:12)
npm ERR!     at fs.js:266:14
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/lib/logger.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/lib/logger.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/lib/logger.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chown '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/node-uuid/benchmark/benchmark-native.c'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/node-uuid/benchmark/benchmark-native.c
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/node-uuid/benchmark/benchmark-native.c
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chown
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:222:7
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/captains-log/test/basic.test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/captains-log/test/basic.test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/captains-log/test/basic.test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs/examples/list.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs/examples/list.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs/examples/list.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/History.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/History.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/History.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/ROADMAP.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/ROADMAP.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/ROADMAP.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-generate/lib/util.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-generate/lib/util.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-generate/lib/util.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/docs/concat-options.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/docs/concat-options.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/docs/concat-options.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/example/raw/bootstrap.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/example/raw/bootstrap.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/example/raw/bootstrap.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/anchor/lib/match/rules.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/anchor/lib/match/rules.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/anchor/lib/match/rules.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/glob/test/00-setup.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/glob/test/00-setup.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/glob/test/00-setup.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-util/docs/cli.html'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-util/docs/cli.html
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-util/docs/cli.html
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/semver/semver.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/semver/semver.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/semver/semver.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/prompt/docs/prompt.html'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/prompt/docs/prompt.html
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/prompt/docs/prompt.html
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-0.1.1.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/has-color/-/has-color-0.1.7.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/has-color/-/has-color-0.1.7.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-path
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/maxmin
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-path
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/maxmin
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-path/-/strip-path-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-path/-/strip-path-0.1.1.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/gzip-size
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/pretty-bytes
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/pretty-bytes
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/gzip-size
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/node_modules/clean-css/History.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.35+
npm ERR! command "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/node" "/home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/node_modules/clean-css/History.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/node_modules/clean-css/History.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/pi/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I already try

```
npm cache clean
rm -rf ~/.npm
```

But no luck :( 
My node version is 0.10.2 and nom is 1.2.15

Comment: Do you have try install NodeJs 0.10.35 and npm version 2.3.0 ?

Comment: Respberry Toolkit : https://github.com/turingou/raspberry

Comment: I try  with different version of nodejs 0.10.9, 0.10.3, 0.10.5 (with npm associate version) but none works. I will try your link but it's not for sailsjs

Comment: try npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: not work without http:// and no luck with this  I have Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/pi/node-v0.10.5-linux-arm-pi/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/History.md' and a lot error after this one... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make it to work by update npm itself like this :

```
npm update -g npm 
npm install -g sails
```

Now I have npm version 2.2.0